# Which box do i check on the U.S Indicia if i am working on STEM OPT on an f1 visa

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am currently working for a company while on STEM OPT and am on an F-1 visa (I have been in the US for less than 3 years). Which of the boxes on the `US Indicia: Reasonable explanation form` do I need to check?

"I am a student at a US educational institution and hold the appropriate visa"

OR

"I have not met the substantial presence test found in section 307.7701(b)-1(c) of the US Treasure Regulations based on the 3 year period calculation I have completed below"

I am inclined towards the 1st explanation but am I still considered a "student at a US educational institution"?

Also, if some other box besides the two mentioned above needs to be checked, please let me know.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the form you are filling?

Comment: @user102008 Thank you for offering to help. I cannot find a link to the form online for some reason. However, I asked my bank and they said the correct option is "I am a student"